# How to extend a React component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Let's say there's a React component that I like, but want to modify. For this example, we'll use Material UI's `LinearProgress`. I want to make a clickable seek bar out of it.

```
class SeekBar extends LinearProgress {
  componentDidMount() {
    super.componentDidMount();
    console.log('my stuff here');
  }
}
```

But I feel like I might be very limited as to what I can do as far as changing what `render` returns. Maybe I'm going about this all wrong, though. If I like a particular React component such as a Material UI component, what is a good, reusable way to customize its look and functionality and make it my own?

Comment: I think a higher order component is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In the ES6/JSX/React world, you can extend component behaviors and values in many ways. I'd recommend one of the following, considering that you use Material UI.

#### First case:

You have two components that extend the `Component` from React:

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return(
      <div>
        <button {...this.props}>
          Click me!
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class RenderComponent extends React.Component {
  clickHandler () {
    console.log('Click fired!')
  }

  render () {
    return(
      <ExampleComponent onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this)} />
    )
  }
}
```

In that example, `onClick` is passed via props inside the rendered `ExampleComponent`. [Example here](https://jsbin.com/kimefuvaqo/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

#### Second case:

This is similar on how Material UI extends their own components:

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  clickHandler () {
    console.log('Click fired!')
  }
}

class RenderComponent extends ExampleComponent {
  render () {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this)}>
          Click me!
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }  
}
```

In this example, you have one component that extends `Component` from React but only has event methods. Then, you extend this component and render your own with the extended behavior. [Here is a live example](https://jsbin.com/julujeguci/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

Hope it helps!

Comment: What about modifying the look of a component, getting into the rendered output and modifying it?

Comment: You can't "override" the render method from the component. What you can do is use `props` to achieve different styles and/or behaviors. Extending my first example in the answer, you could pass custom class names via `props`, check here: https://jsbin.com/wadekateho/1/edit?html,js,console,output -
Using this thought, you could pass boolean values or even pre-rendered code inside the `props`.

Comment: I was thinking of trying a structure similar to the second case. I researched before trying it to see if there is such a use. I think second case is the best for website that uses different layout for mobile and desktop.

Answer (score 4):

One way is:

```
export default class Seekbar extends React.Component{

   // perform any modification

   render(){
      return <LinearProgress ...changes/>
   }
}
```

Another way is a Higher Order Component, HOC.  Here's a great blog with more info: http://natpryce.com/articles/000814.html

I think with Material-UI your best bet would be to wrap it and make any modifications you'd like.  Unfortunately this project is very tightly coupled thanks to things like inline styles and their thememanager so taking a single component out may be difficult.  HOC would be better for things like sharing some smart functionality across components, like passing a "theme" prop automatically to components.